# Cross Domain Access of a asp.net webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, jsonp

i have a simple html page having this-:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.bebas.co.in/myservice.asmx/functionName?callback=?",                     
                           function(response) {  
                           //manipulate response

                           });
///
```

and in myservice.cs file I have this..

```
[WebService(Namespace = "")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class myservice : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public myservice()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }


        [WebMethod]
        public string functionName()
        {
               //database access..
                Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                result = JsonMethods.ToJson(dsResult.Tables[0]);
              //other operations...
                return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
        }
    }.................
```

I want to have cross domain access...but am unable to do so..firebug gives me 
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in...

what should i do?.

Comment: What is the full firebug error? Are you using AJAX? Firebug is probably expecting HTML, but a web service response is SOAP.

Comment: Actually, your webservice isn't even compiling. Visiting http://www.bebas.co.in/myservice.asmx from a web browser gives a yellow screen. Does myservice.cs exist, and does its code compile?

Comment: @justin..plz ignore the url..consider it as an example..service works fine at its original domain..:) ..plz help

Comment: yeah..there is some format mismatch issue(that is all i cn guess).. may b xml vs json?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use custom URL parameters in .asmx services. Aren't they supposed to all match parameters of your service method?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a web service to return JSON. Just put your code in a normal webform (with NO markup, just a blank .aspx), and call it from Page_Load() in the code-behind (.aspx.cs).

Or you could use an [HttpHandler](http://dylanphillips.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/custom-httphandlers-in-asp-net-4-0-help-is-on-the-way/).

Comment: @Justin..am forbidden to use .aspx..i need to do it through a web service..(and yes..it worked fine with .aspx)

Comment: If you must use a web service, then you must process the SOAP response. Since you are already using jquery, you might want to try this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient